# Python URL querystring variable passing is not working

Tags: python-2.7, apigee

I am fetching data using `APIGEE` management API call. When I keep the querystring as a static value my code works but as soon as I am using the date variable it's failing. If anyone can help me achieving it would be really helpful.

```
import base64
import json 
import sys
import time
import urllib
import easygui
import requests
import easygui

apigeeurl = raw_input("Enter the IP of the Management Server: ")
which_api = raw_input("Do you want traffic details for apps or apis: ") 
which_env = raw_input("Which Environment from Organization aig: ")
start_date = raw_input("What is the start date as mm/dd/yyyy: ")
end_date = raw_input("What is the end date as mm/dd/yyyy: ")
pstmnauth = raw_input("Enter your auhorization: ")

url = "http://"+apigeeurl+":8080/v1/organizations/aig/environments/" + which_env + "/stats/"+which_api

querystring = '{"select":"sum(message_count)","timeRange":"03/20/2018 00:00~03/25/2018 00:00","timeUnit":"day"}'

# querystring = {"select":"sum(message_count)","timeRange":'"'+start_date+' 00:00~'+end_date+' 00:00"',"timeUnit":"day"}

headers = {
    'authorization': "Basic "+pstmnauth,
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```

Comment: Did you try to do a trace and debug it on the Apigee cosnole ?

Comment: I am not sure if trace session will work as this is APIGEE default (given) management call; I am not even sure how to trace management API. Need suggestion. Please help.

Comment: Try outputting or printing both static and variable querystring to the console and see if they match ? Since your code works with a static querystring I am guessing the problem would lie with how the queryString is made